# UglifyJs - minified mangled variable recovers at runtime its original name

Tags: javascript, fabricjs, create-react-app, uglifyjs

In my codebase I have this custom code that interacts with fabric.js:

```
export function cropToCircle(object) {
    let minDim = Math.min(object.width, object.height);
    window.lastMinDim = minDim;
    return object.set('clipTo', ctx => {
        if (typeof minDim === 'undefined') minDim = window.lastMinDim || 1000;
        ctx.arc(0, 0, minDim / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    });
}
```

It gets minified by uglify.js into this string, which I present here prettified:

```
function s(e) {
    var t = Math.min(e.width, e.height);
    return window.lastMinDim = t, e.set('clipTo', function (e) {
        'undefined' === typeof t && (t = window.lastMinDim || 1e3), e.arc(0, 0, t / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !0);
    });
}
```

At runtime this minified code works well in most invocations. But there is one, triggered by Fabric's `canvas.renderAll()` in which I get an error "Reference Error: e is not defined".
The error comes during the execution of the callback of `e.set('clipTo')`.

The amazing thing is that if I check in the debugger, I see that the callback is being run as a snippet where the input param is called `ctx` instead of `e`. Here is the screen shot:

[image: ctx is back]

Obviously if the input param is renamed to `ctx` by the interpreter, then the `e` inside the body has no definition; but it is like the browser "knows" that `e` was called originally `ctx`, which does not make any sense to me, unless Fabric (which uses `ctx` all over the place) has somehow influence on the execution of this snippet.

This is verified in both Chrome 65 and Firefox 59.

I have tried in every way I could imagine to change something in the source code in order to avoid the appearance of `ctx`:

- rename `ctx` to `context` in the source code
- extract the callback into a separated named function

But still no joy.

Can anyone explain why the browser is renaming the input variable of this callback?

Comment: It's renamed for doing name of  this variable shorter. I this case `ctx` is a local variable. In this case minificator  can  safety  rename it.

Comment: I am asking about variable renaming during _execution_, not during _minification_. Pls read my question more carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very remarcable accident. Never seen anything like this and, apparently, no one else seems to have anything to say about it.

The solution I have found is to protect the param name `ctx` from mangling during the minification.

The relevant UglifyJS config is:

```
  mangle: {
    except: ['ctx'],
  },
```

which creates the following minified/prettified code:

```
function s(e) {
    var t = Math.min(e.width, e.height);
    return window.lastMinDim = t, e.set('clipTo', function (ctx) {
        'undefined' === typeof t && (t = window.lastMinDim || 1e3), ctx.arc(0, 0, t / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, !0);
    });
}
```

This way the browser still overrides the input param name with `ctx`, but in this case the function body makes still sense during its execution.